# Poisson Equation with constant source function and simple boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I need to solve
$$\nabla^2u(x,y) = constant$$
with $0\leq x  \leq a$, $0\leq y \leq b$ and $u(x,y) = 0$ on the rectangle with vertices $(0,0),(a,0),(0,b),(a,b)$

I know the solution is unique since the difference between any two solutions is a solution to $$\nabla^2u(x,y) = 0$$ which has the trivial solution $u = 0$.

I feel like there is a simple way to do this or even guess a solution in this constant source two dimensional case but I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean that $u(x,y)=0$ on the *boundary* of that rectangle?

Comment: Yep $u(x,y)=0$ on the boundary of the rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $v(x,y)=x(x-a)/2$ which satisfies $\nabla^{2}v=1$ and
$$
                v(0,y)=0,\;\;\; v(a,y)=0,\\
                v(x,0)=x(x-a)/2,\;\;\; v(x,b)=x(x-a)/2.
$$
Then solve for $\nabla^{2}w_1=0$ such that
$$
                   w_1(0,y)=0,\;\;\; w_1(a,y)=0,\\
                   w_1(x,0)=0,\;\;\; w_1(x,b)=x(x-a)/2.
$$
It follows that $w_2(x,y)=w_1(x,b-y)$ satisfies $\nabla^{2}w_2=0$ and
$$
                     w_2(0,y)=0,\;\;\; w_1(a,y)=0,\\
                     w_2(x,0)=x(x-a)/2,\;\;\;w_2(x,b)=0.
$$
The desired solution is $u=v-w_1-w_2$.