# Integrating a second-order partial differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I haven't dealt with solving many partial differential equations before. How would I go about solving:

$$
A = \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial y^{2}}
$$

where *A* is a constant.

Ideally, I could get an equation of  *v(x,y)*  but I am not sure if that's possible. If there isn't a "pretty" solution to this. How could I go about approximating the solution?

Thanks

Comment: You need boundary conditions. See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459776/poisson-equation-with-constant-source-function-and-simple-boundary-conditions

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial y^{2}}=A
$$Without boundary condition one cannot recommend a specific convenient method.

An obvious form of solution is for example :
$$v(x,y)=\frac{A}{2}x^2+f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)$$
$f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions.

$\frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial x^{2}}=A+f''(x+iy)+g''(x-iy)$

$f''(X)=\frac{d^2f(X)}{dX^2}$

$\frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial y^{2}}=(i^2)f''(x+iy)+(-i)^2g''(x-iy)=-f''(x+iy)-g''(x-iy)$

$\frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial y^{2}}=\left(A+f''(x+iy)+g''(x-iy)\right)+\left(-f''(x+iy)-g''(x-iy)\right)=A\quad$ which satisfies the PDE.