# Integrating a second-order partial differential equation w/ boundary conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I haven't dealt with solving many partial differential equations before. How would I go about solving:

$$
A = \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial y^{2}}
$$

where *A* is a constant and *v* is a function of velocity.

The boundary conditions follow an equilateral triangular shape. [Here is an image of the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVvJw.png). All of the vertices of the triangle have a velocity of zero:

$$
v(-2a,0) = v(a,a\sqrt{3}) = v(a,-a\sqrt{3}) = 0 
$$

And all of the edges of the triangle have a velocity of zero:

$$
v(x,\frac{x+2a}{\sqrt{3}})=v(x,-\frac{x+2a}{\sqrt{3}})=0
$$

Ideally, I could get an equation of  *v(x,y)*  but I am not sure if that's possible. If there isn't a "pretty" solution to this. How could I go about approximating the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, the linear form of boundary conditions draw us to try a polynomial equation as solution of the PDE. For example one can try the simplest form :
$$v=c_1x^2+c_2y^2+c_3xy+c_4x+c_5y+c_6$$
Putting it into the PDE and into the conditions leads to the system of equations :
$$\begin{cases}
2c_1+2c_2=A \\
\frac13 c_3+c1+\frac13 c_2\sqrt{3}=0\\ 
\frac23 c_2a\sqrt{3}+\frac43 c_3a+\frac13 c_5\sqrt{3}+c4=0\\
\frac43 c_3a^2+\frac23 c_5a\sqrt{3}+c_6=0\\
\frac13 c_3+c1-\frac13 c_2\sqrt{3}=0\\ 
-\frac23 c_2a\sqrt{3}+\frac43 c_3a-\frac13 c_5\sqrt{3}+c4=0\\
\frac43 c_3a^2-\frac23 c_5a\sqrt{3}+c_6=0\\ 
\end{cases}$$
Solving the system leads to :
$$\begin{cases}
c_1=-\frac14 A \\
c_2=0 \\
c_3=\frac34 A \\
c_4=-Aa \\
c5=0 \\
c_6=-Aa^2 \\
\end{cases}$$
Putting them into the second order polynomial and after simplification :
$$\boxed{v(x,y)=-\frac{1}{4}Ax^2+\frac{3}{4}Ay^2-aAx-aA}$$

The above method is much simpler than using the general solution (See : [Integrating a second-order partial differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3943775/integrating-a-second-order-partial-differential-equation) )
$$v(x,y)=\frac{A}{2}x^2+f(x+iy)+g(x+iy)$$
The determination of the functions $f$ and $g$ in order to satisfy the boundary conditions is a boring calculus leading to :
$$f(Z)=g(Z)=-\frac{3A}{8}Z^2-\frac{aA}{2}Z-\frac{aA}{2}$$
With $Z=x+iy$ and $Z=x-iy$ respectively the solution $v(x,y)$ is the same as above.